# What is the order of execution of alter operations in an alter query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql-5.7, alter-table

Consider the following queries

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (f2 INT);

ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD COLUMN f1 INT, DROP COLUMN f1;
```

In the above query drop column seems to happen before add column and query fails. Similarly rename column happens before add column.

Alter does not seem to happen in the given order and there are number of alter operations such as modify, add/drop index, add/drop unique key. I am not able find any MySQL documentation for their order of execution.

What is the order of execution of alter operations in an alter query in MySQL?

Comment: Seems like the declarative language gotcha vs imperative